# Angular: The $ in scope variables

Tags: angularjs

I cannot find any documentation regarding the proper use of $ in scope variables. My code runs fine without them and the closest answer google gave was that it is a convention used by JQuery programmers.What are the best practices and when should it be used in Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more details in here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#angular_namespace

> Angular Namespace
>   To prevent accidental name collision, Angular prefixes names of objects which could potentially collide with $. Please do not use the $ prefix in your code as it may accidentally collide with Angular code.